# Editing RuleSets with RuleSetDialog

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, workflow-foundation, rule-engine

RuleSet class has Name and Description properties. Rule class has Name and Description properties.

As far as I can see, using RuleSetDialog form for runtime creation of RuleSets only exposes Rule.Name. Other three properties are nowhere to be found and I would like to use them especially Rule.Description.

Perhaps I'm missing something here. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

it's a limitation of the RuleSetDialog. You can't edit the rule description using it.